# Agrupar resultados de duas colunas de tabelas diferentes no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados MySQL:

**TAB_A**:

| usua_id | dt_nasc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-06-28 |
| **2** | **2001-06-28** |
| 3 | 2002-06-28 |
| **4** | **2001-06-28** |

**TAB_B**:

| insc_id | usua_id | categ_id | nota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | **2** | **3** | **7** |
| 4 | **4** | **3** | **7** |

Tenho que retornar ***o agrupamento*** de **TAB_A.dt_nasc** com **TAB_B.nota**

Ou seja, preciso retornar no caso ai a categoria id 3, que teve inscrição de usuário com a mesma nota e datas de nascimento iguais

tentei com:

```
    SELECT categ_id, nota , COUNT(*) tot  
    FROM TAB_A a JOIN TAB_B b on a.usua_id = b.usua_id 
    GROUP by dt_nasc, nota having tot > 1
```

também com subquery e nada:

```
SELECT b.carg_id , b.nota
FROM TAB_B b
where a.usua_id IN (    
    SELECT usua_id
    from TAB_A
    where dt_nasc in (
        SELECT dt_nasc
        from TAB_A
        GROUP by dt_nasc
        having COUNT(dt_nasc) > 1
    )
)
GROUP by b.nota, b.carg_id
```

O retorno deveria ser algo do tipo:

| categ_id | dt_nasc | nota |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2001-06-28 | 7 |

Alguém já possou por um problema parecido??